# SwiftUI catch RedirectUri post back from web based login form

Tags: swift, oauth, swiftui

I'm writing an iPhone application using swiftUI that requires users to authenticate via a web form to obtain an access_token to make subsequant API calls.

I'm using a NavigationLink to handle the login process:

```
NavigationLink(destination: LoginView()) {
    Text("Login")
}
```

Which loads this View and opens the login page with the clientid and redirecturi:

```
struct LoginView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "mysite.com\auth?clientid=myid&redirecturi=anything.com")!)
        uiView.load(request)

    }
}
```

On a web client the passed in redirecturi would be called by the login form to postback the auth token - but on the iPhone, is there a way to catch the post from the redirect?

Am open for suggestions if there is a better way in SwiftUi to handle the web login / redirect postback flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after some research and playing around learning a bit more Swift I've discovered an answer so I thought I'd post here in case anyone else finds the same issue.

The navigation from the WkWebView can be caught with a WKNavigationDelegate like this:

```
extension LoginView: WKNavigationDelegate
{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
         print(webView.url)
         decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

However you can't just extend the original struct so the original LoginView had to be converted into a class and the navigationDelegate assigned like this:

```
final internal class LoginView: NSObject, UIViewRepresentable {
    var _loginWebView: WKWebView!

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        _loginWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        _loginWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        return _loginWebView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "mysite.com\auth?clientid=myid&redirecturi=anything.com")!)
        uiView.load(request)
    }

}
```